# Blocked CSR SPMV Implementation

Tags: cuda

Has anybody implemented Blocked CSR/ELL SPMV in CUDA?? Where can I get the source code?. I'm finding it hard to block the matrix in CSR format

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone will give you the implementation. You can check this paper on [Efficient SPMV on GPUs using CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/66889/nvr-2008-004.pdf). They even talk about CSR kernel.